# I'm using a partitioning tool to run my computer, it has a linux os on it and for some reason it won't read my USB

Tags: linux, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

Recently my computer died on me, I have been trying everything to fix it. it will not read my HDD, I've tried multiple Hard drives none work. I came across this paritioning tool called PartedMagic, it allows me to run a small version of linux to run their programs. i have been trying to move the linux base to a bootable USB to prevent running my CD/DVD drive running all the time. Is it just my driver being made for windows 8 the reason why it won't register any USB Devices.

Any information helps I'm new to linux. 
Thanks everyone, (in advance)
Krooked

Comment: Please try to be more polite in your language. Not everyone here likes to see profanity.

Answer (score 0):

PartedMagic is a general purpose hard disk management solution containing tools for disk partitioning, disk cloning, data rescue, disk erasing and benchmarking. This size of all these tools together makes it harder to boot PartedMagic from a USB flash drive than it is to boot a live USB that contains only the partitioning tool, but maybe you need all of the tools in PartedMagic and that's why you downloaded the PartedMagic iso file.

If your computer has hardware problems, then PartedMagic is not the best partitioning tool to use. A better choice would be the GParted live USB because the GParted live USB runs only from RAM by default, so it is more robust when it comes to booting it. The official instructions for installing GParted on a USB flash drive are at [GParted Live on USB](https://gparted.org/liveusb.php).

Comment: My only other computer to use is a mac and often times it won't let me run most windows programs. When i tried making a bootable usb from, windows them self, it wouldn't let me run it.

Comment: You can install a program in your Mac called UNetbootin and make a bootable live USB with it. I have made a live GParted USB using UNetbootin and it works.